# Notification Area Balloon Windows 7 not working

Tags: windows-7, audio

Whenever a system notification appears, i do not hear the sound. I have it enabled in the sound control panel, but system notification sounds do not work.

Comment: I am assuming your sound generally works?

Answer (score 1):

Check this folder, there should be 20 wav files in there.

> C:\Windows\Media\Sonata

Comment: So what? This is a sound theme folder and will only affect the asker's problem if they are trying to use that theme.